# Task returns "call thread can't access this object"

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, exception, task

I want to create an array with all the plugins installed on streamlinks and then compare it with a given string, to check if the app has a supporting plugin for the given site. I don't want to freeze the app for that, so a while loop inside a sync method would not fit me, so I tried to do it with Tasks.

This is the code of my app:

```cs
private void SupportCheckButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task<bool> task = Task.Run(async () => await Methods.isSiteSupported(LinkText.Text));

    task.Wait();
    if (task.Result)
    {
        cmdOutputLabel.AppendText(new Uri(Methods.FormatedUrl(LinkText.Text)).Host + " is supported.");
    }
    else
    {
        cmdOutputLabel.AppendText(new Uri(Methods.FormatedUrl(LinkText.Text)).Host + " is not supported. Yet...");
    }
}
```

This is the code for my `library`:

```cs
private static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
        plugins = e.Data.Split(',');
}

public static async Task<bool> isSiteSupported(string site)
{
    try
    {
        site = FormatedUrl(site);
        if (GetUrlResponse(site))
        {
            string siteDomain = new Uri(site).Host;
            string[] siteDivided = siteDomain.Split('.');

            if (siteDivided.Length == 2)
                siteDomain = siteDivided[0];
            else if (siteDivided.Length >= 2)
            {
                siteDomain = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < siteDivided.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    siteDomain += siteDivided[i];
                }
            }

            Process proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "CMD.exe",
                    Arguments = "/C streamlink --plugins",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            if (plugins == null)
            {
                await GetPluginList();
            }
            return plugins.Contains(siteDomain);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static async Task<string> GetPluginList()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        while (plugins == null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        if (plugins.Length > 0)
        {
            if (plugins[0].Contains("Loaded plugins: "))
                plugins[0] = plugins[0].Remove(plugins[0].IndexOf("Loaded plugins: "), 10);
            for (int i = 0; i < plugins.Length; i++)
            {
                plugins[i] = plugins[i].Trim();
            }
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

But after many tries I was not able to do it properly. Right now, with this exact code, it returns an `InvalidOperationException` saying that the Call Thread can't access `Task.Wait();` object, because it is being used in another Thread. Anyhow I can't see what other thread is using it.

Comment: Did you try using a thread-save collection?

Comment: Probably your DataReceivedEventHandler is causing some trouble, this is raised from another process, and created in a thread, the thread might terminate while the process still runs. And a process even get's another address space and cannot share memory with the initial process. This is really a complicated setup.

Comment: In the Task you are already calling await. So you don't need to do task.Wait();

Comment: @Holger Any tips on a easier way to do it? i ended up with this setup because i didn't want to re-write some parts, but i'm up for a re-write now if that means less errors and more flexible results...

Comment: @Twenty will try in a few minutes, also, very good grammar checking and editing, was amazed by how quick it was too...

Comment: @PedroCosta No, cause I don't know what you try to do. In what way does your process end ? If it has a longer lifetime than your thread, then your eventhandler will become invalid. What is your thread doing ? It waits for a first plugin to registered and then it terminates. If your started process freezes for some reason, also your internal thread is frozen in an endless loop. It waits forever for input.